# Convert <img> to <amp-img>

Tags: amp-html

Which is the default way to convert an `<img>` to a `<amp-img>`?

I explain myself: In the site that I'm converting to AMP I have lot of images without widht and height e.g.:

`<img src="/img/image.png" alt="My image">`

If I not specify the layout, the `layout="container"` is set by default and the most of the images throw the following error:

> amp-img error: Layout not supported for: container

In the other hand, the most of the images don't fit with the responsive layout, which is recommended by Google for most of the cases

I have been checking the types of layout on the documentation:

- [Layout System](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/layout_system/)
- [Layout & Media queries](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout)

But any of them seems to fit with an image that have to be shown as its real size, not specifying width or height.

So, in that case, which is the equivalent in AMP?

Answer (score 3):

As you are saying you have multiple images, it's better you use the '**layout="responsive"**', with that, you will make your images responsive atleast.
Now regarding the *Width* and *Height*. They are must. If you read the purpose of AMP, one of them is to make the pages '**Jumping/Flickering Free Content**', which happens if there is no width mentioned for Images. 
By Specifying the Width, the Browser (mobile browser), can calculate the precise space and keep it for that Image and show the Content after that. In that way, there wont' be any flickering of the content, as the page and images are loaded.

Regarding the re-writing of your HTML, one tip I can provide is, you can write some small utility with PHP, Python or Node JavaScript, which can actually read the source image, calculate their dimensions and replace your IMG tags.

Hope this helps and wish you good luck for your AMP powered site :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `layout=fixed` but you will still need to add the `width` and `height`, so you may need to calculate those for your images.